# How to count a no in array without loop?

Tags: java

Let's assume we have an array of `10` elements `a[] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2};` and if have to check the number of occurrences of an specific element say `3` . Then how I will able to count it *without loop*? Because the number of elements may be so many. My question is: *is there any Java method to find it*?

Comment: How would you be able to find the number of occurences without looking at each and every element?

Comment: There will always be a loop, even if you don't see it.

Comment: I don't see anyway to answer the question without touching each element in the array at least once.  You might be able to use a stream to avoid an explicit loop, but internally I would be that it is looping.

Comment: You could use recursion instead of looping.

Comment: @yshavit A serious overkill tho.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the OP asks "is there any java method to find it" so I guess a stream is ok because it's a "java method"...

Comment: @MarounMaroun If you're doing this for engineering, sure. If this is a homework assignment, it's definitely a reasonable "early in learning about recursion" exercise.

Comment: @yshavit I can't disagree with that.

Comment: without extra context we can only guess what he's looking for

Comment: If you know the array length is always 10, it shouldn’t be too hard to write 10 if statements each of which increase a counter if the element is in a specific index of the array (for anything resembling production code I’d still recommend the loop at any time, though).

Comment: Is recursion allowed?

Comment: If this is an assignment, could it be that you are supposed to solve it using recursion? You may declare `public static int count(int elementToCount, int[] a, int fromIndex)` and implement it with a recursive call in which `fromIndex` is incremented by 1. To count the entire array, call with a 0 in the last argument. To count 3s, call with 3 as the first arg (or hardcode the 3 and leave out the first parameter).

Answer (score 0):

Without *writing* a traditional for loop:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2);

long occurences = list.stream().filter(n -> n == 3).count();

System.out.print(occurences);
```

Comment: How do you think `count` is implemented?

Comment: Nick Venderhoven didn’t say without using a loop. He said without writing one. Whether he answered the question — let’s leave to the OP to decide. @MarounMaroun

Comment: @OleV.V. It's not useful in any case. If it's an assignment, OP won't be learning anything, and if it's for performance things, no significant improvements here.

Comment: I guess you were not asking for `mapToLong(e -> 1L).sum()` - well in my defense, it might be interesting to people Googling "is there any java method to count a no in array without loop?" - maybe we can edit the question and flag it as duplicate?

Comment: @MarounMaroun It's useful if you want to learn more about programming. It's always good to see something being done in multiple ways.

Comment: It's not an assignment , I was solving a problem and  problem was terminated due to 'TLE' so I need to ask a this Question .. The main problem was to count the no of  elements of an array..

Answer (score 0):

With an array which is an object where you you have to iterate over elements to know each one, a loop is unavoidable.

> My question is: is there any Java method to find it?

Yes but you should use a structure more suitable to your need such as a Map for example.

The idea is to use a Map to initialize values and the associated frequency. In this way, you didn't need any longer to perform loop when you want to know the frequency of a integer value.

```
public Map<Integer,Integer> createWithElements(int... values) {
 Map<Integer,Integer> nbOccurencesByValue = new HashMap<>();
  for (int value : values){
    Integer actualNbOccurence = nbOccurencesByValue.get(value); 
    if (actualNbOccurence==null){
        actualNbOccurence=0;
    }
     nbOccurencesByValue.put(value, ++actualNbOccurence);
  }
 return nbOccurencesByValue;
}
```

How to use it :

```
Map<Integer,Integer> nbOccurencesByValue = createWithElements(2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2);
Integer nbOccurenceFor3Number = nbOccurencesByValue.get(3);
```

Comment: As note in the comments, a loop is not unavoidable. The other option is recursion, which may be exactly what the OP needs (if this is a homework assignment for recursion, which is what I'm guessing the no-loop requirement is getting at).

Comment: loop and recursion may often address the same need. So, yes, if it is a homework it is maybe what the teacher expects but as a general way,  I prefer not to propose or implement himself recursion as a solution when it is possible because it brings often undesirable complexity and makes the maintenance harder.